# Count rows from one tables of users in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create  a query for project listings that would give the number of registered applications, excluding the ones for which the user does not exist.
In this case, considering user 10 does not exist, I should have the query results as folows:

RESULTS

```
 +----+------------+--------------+
    | id |  project   | applications |
    +----+------------+--------------+
    |  1 | MyProject1 |            3 |
    |  2 | MyProject2 |            0 |
    |  3 | MyProject3 |            0 |
    +----+------------+--------------+
```

## TABLES

```
   Projects
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | MyProject1 |
|  2 | MyProject2 |
|  3 | MyProject3 |
+----+------------+


applications
+----+------+------------+
| id | user | project_id |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 |    3 |          1 |
|  2 |    4 |          1 |
|  3 |    5 |          1 |
|  4 |   10 |          1 |
+----+------+------------+



users
+----+---------+
| id |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Smith   |
|  2 | John    |
|  3 | Paul    |
|  4 | Chris   |
|  5 | Gabriel |
+----+---------+
```

The below query is not excluding the non-existing users:

```
SELECT  `projects` . * , (

                                                                                SELECT COUNT( * ) 
                                                                                FROM  `applications` 
                                                                                WHERE  `applications`.`project_id` =  `projects`.`id` 
                                                                                AND EXISTS (
                                                                                SELECT  `applications`.`id` 
                                                                                FROM  `applications` ,  `users`,`project`
                                                                                WHERE  `application`.`user` =  `users`.`id` AND `applications`.`project_id` = `project`.`id`
                                                                                )
                                                                                )  AS `applications`
                                                                                FROM  `projects` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: That looks horrible. How can there be a user ID in table applications that doesn't exist in table users? There should be a foreign key on it. Or is there any reason not to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks overly complicated. This should do:

```
select 
  id, 
  name as project, 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from applications a
    where a.project_id = p.id
    and a.user in (select id from users)
  ) as applications
from projects p;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `left join` and `group by`:

```
select p.id, p.name, count(u.id)
from projects p left join
     applications a
     on p.id = a.project_id left join
     users u
     on a.user_id = u.id
group by p.id, p.name;
```

However, you might want to think about fixing the data.  It seems like there should be foreign key relationships between applications and projects and applications and users.  The ability to have an invalid user means that there is no valid foreign key relationship to users.

Comment: This one is running very slow.
I have tried the query in the post edit but it is not excluding the non-existing users:

Comment: Add a test over the left join in > where u.id is not null

Comment: @valiD . . . (1) This should be pretty fast if you have primary keys on the tables; (2) This should not be counting non-existing users.  That is what the `count(u.id)` does.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous solution

```
select p.id, p.name, count(u.id)
from projects p left join
     applications a
     on p.id = a.project_id left join
     users u
     on a.user = u.id
where u.id is not null
group by p.id, p.name;
```

When you do a left join, if the search value doesn't exists, it returns null. Then filtering by excluding null users, will give you the result.

Please find a sqlfiddle to illustrate it : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbfec6/3

But easiest solution would be

```
select p.id, p.name, count(u.id)
from projects p,applications a, users u
where a.user = u.id
 and p.id = a.project_id 
group by p.id, p.name;
```